# Is there any battery management software to work with a laptop plugged to AC power so as to save the battery lifetime?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, laptop, power-management, battery

I was used to remove the battery of my laptop whenever I worked with my computer plugged to AC power and to load the battery with the computer switched off so as to save the lifetime of the battery.   But on modern laptops it is not possible to remove the battery.

I recently purchased a Toshiba Satellite L50-B-18C laptop and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

I would like to know if there is any battery management software to work with Ubuntu which allows to stop battery charging before it reaches its 100% capacity and to make it charge again before it reaches a threshold. Some people told me that such utilities exist for Windows operating systems and I was wondering if similar utilities can be found to work under Ubuntu.

Comment: Batteries *like* to be fully charged.  They don't like to be fully discharged, so just plug it back in or shut it down before the battery gets too low.

Comment: Just leave the battery in, that's where its designed to be. Repeatedly charging and discharging it will just wear it out

Comment: @Wilf: That's precisely the problem: I don't want the battery be worn out.

Comment: There is no problem with leaving it charge after 100%. The battery and the system that charges it were created to make sure than when it reached 100% or close to it, there would be not "overcharge". Like Wilf said, leave the battery charging how long you want, it won't wear out. It will in fact loose battery life faster if you discharge it completely and then try to charge it back to 100%. For a battery management software, Linux already comes with some pretty good ones and the Unity panel shows a battery icon for it.

Comment: By the way, in this [web site](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_increase_the_runtime_of_your_wireless_device) you can find a lot of interesting information about how batteries work.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado: The problem is not that the battery will be overcharged. The point is that, since the computer is working, once it reaches the 100%, battery will start to discharge. Then it will start to charge again until it reaches the 100%, then it will begin to discharge again... Maintaining that for a long period of time will overheat the battery and will stress the battery a lot. More details can be found in the link of my previous comment.

Comment: Aah! got it friend. So it has a problem when it reaches the 100% where it starts a charge/discharge loop. Have you per chance tried powertop which helps a bit finding out what causes stuff like that. What you have then is a serious problem. Could be hardware that is reading the battery correctly or doing the help "saving" job wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why batteries are not removable as much anymore cause they do not work like they used to. Batteries these days do not over charge so by removing the battery you are not doing anything. The best thing is to not let the battery run under 5% and this is what will maximize your battery life cycle.

Comment: "By removing the battery you are not doing anything": well, at least you are not overheating the battery.